# Cross-origin request with basic auth

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, cors

I'm trying to make cross-origin requests work with asp.net MVC4, but I'm not getting things to work.

- The problem

The controller responds to the pre-flight OPTIONS request, but doesn't set Access-Control-Allow-* headers

- The 'solution'(?)

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CORS-support-in-ASPNET-Web-01e9980a#content should be enough. But the HttpControllerConfigurationAttribute it hinges on isn't part of the final MVC 4.

- The question

How can I make MVC set the headers I want(tm)[1]? Preferably through an attribute on an action, but doing it 'manually' somehow is fine with me too.

[1] A flexible solution would be great, with a cors-allow-origin attribute taking a string, a cors-allow-methods taking a list of HttpMethod, and a cors-allow-headers taking a list of strings - or an EnableCors attribute with all three parameters. But having the following fixed list should suffice

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: AUTHORIZATION
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.45 which handles it for me, and works(tm) - though not 100% like I'd like it.